# Problems With Lex

Tags: c, linux, lex

I am writing a software in C.  For that purpose I use lex.  I wrote a piece of code in C to create a [symbol table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162137/c-symbol-table-problem) and manage it.  So, whenever lex finds a new symbol, it puts it in a symbol table.  Problem is, when I try to print all results from symbol table, I get output I didn't expect.
If, for example, the input file was:

```
int main(){}
```

the output should be:

```
int
main
(
)
{
}
```

but the output is:

```
int main(){}
main(){}
(){}
...
```

and so on.
The function used for printing is something like this

```
void print_entries(struct symtab *start) {
   struct symtab *s = start;
   while(s != NULL) {
      printf("%s\n", s->name);
      s = s->next;
   }
}
```

Here is the code for adding new symbols:

```
void add_entry(char* name, int type, struct symtab *start)
{
   struct symtab *new;
   new = malloc(sizeof(struct symtab));
   last_entry(start)->next = new;
   new->name = name;
   new->type = type;
   new->next = NULL;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: (This might be a silly question, but are you only calling print_entries once?)

Comment: Yes, i'm only calling it once :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought I should ask :P

Comment: It looks like you're not creating your symbols correctly.  If you look at your output, the name doesn't hold the contents of the token but rather is just a pointer into the text.  You should allocate the names to hold just the token.

Comment: I noticed the same thing.But i can't see an error in my code.

Comment: And how is `add_entry()` called?  You haven't allocated anything for the name here.

Comment: Jeff is correct. You are stashing pointers into the input buffer in your `->name` fields; you need to allocate space for the correct number of characters (which it appears you currently do not know in `add_entry` - that'll need to be passed in), copy, and nul-terminate.

Comment: Can you give me example code for that? :)

Comment: easiest would be to use `strdup(yytext)` in your lex code that calls add_entry.  Alternately use `new->name = strdup(name);` in add_entry

Comment: I could be misremembering, but I thought `yytext` wasn't guaranteed to be nul-terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the symbol names into the symbol table entries.  If for some peculiar reason your system does not have `strdup()` already, then use:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strdup(const char *str)
{
   size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
   char *dup = malloc(len);
   if (dup != 0)
       memmove(dup, str, len);
   return dup;
}
```

(In this context, I could use `memcpy()` safely; I use `memmove()` because it always works and `memcpy()` does not.  And I use `memmove()` because I know exactly how long the string is so the copy doesn't need to test each character for nullness as it goes.)

With `strdup()` on hand:

```
void add_entry(char* name, int type, struct symtab *start)
{
   struct symtab *sym;
   sym = malloc(sizeof(struct symtab));
   last_entry(start)->next = sym;
   sym->name = strdup(name);
   sym->type = type;
   sym->next = NULL;
}
```

Note that this still omits the error checking from the two memory allocations, which is not a good habit to get into.  I've revised it to use `sym` rather than `new` because the latter is a C++ keyword and I avoid using those as identifiers, even in C code.